# Trying to make div sticky above all other components

Tags: ssh, digital-ocean

I have a problem that is driving me nuts.

I've been using Digital Ocean for a while and I recently created a droplet that when I create a user account, let's say "deploy", and try to ssh in, I get Permission denied (publickey).

I've gone as far as to create a new key and replace my old one, but I get the same error.

Has anyone run into this?

I ran a debug:

```
OpenSSH_7.3p1, LibreSSL 2.4.1
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 104.236.182.137 [104.236.182.137] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/[user name]/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/[user name]/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/[user name]/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/[user name]/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/[user name]/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/[user name]/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/[user name]/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/[user name]/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 104.236.182.137:22 as 'deploy'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: [server key replaced for security]
debug1: Host '104.236.182.137' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/[user name]/.ssh/known_hosts:51
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/[user name]/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/[user name]/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/[user name]/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/[user name]/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: How is this question related to the title? Why did you ask [essentially the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42813031/13317) twice within a few minutes?

Comment: Hi Kenster, thanks for catching that. Didn't realize I duplicated the question. Thought I was updating.